# how to use the selected variable for th:text

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
    <select>
        <option th:each="city:${cities}"
                th:value="${city.value}"
                th:utext="${city.name}"/>
    </select>

    <div th:text="here"></div>
```

how to get the selected value from  to th:text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use jQuery or javascript to get and set the selected value like bellow

```js
var city=$('#city :selected').text();
$('#city_selected').val(city)
```

```html
 <select id="city">
        <option th:each="city:${cities}"
                th:value="${city.value}"
                th:utext="${city.name}"/>
    </select>

    <div >
    <input id="city_selected"/>
    </div>
```